# Getting HTML5 YouTube player to fit in a UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, youtube-api, html5-video, youtube-iframe-api

I used to (in iOS 6) be able to just "tell" the YouTube player what width and height it should stretch to and no problem.

This code was working before in iOS 6, but **now in iOS 7 it's not working at all**.

But now I have to put in MUCH (3x) higher values for height and width **than the screen it self** but that is of course not a solution because the size of the devices varies.

This is code that is run when button is pressed

```
NSString *player = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><style>body{margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;}</style></head> 
<body> 

<div id=\"player\"></div> 

<script>   
var tag = document.createElement('script'); 
tag.src = \"http://www.youtube.com/player_api\"; 
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];      
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag); 
var player; 

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() 
{ 
   player = new YT.Player('player', { width:'%0.0fpx', height:'%0.0fpx', videoId:'%@',
   playerVars: {playsinline : 1, rel:0, showinfo:0}, events: { 'onReady': onPlayerReady, } });
 } 
   function onPlayerReady(event) { event.target.playVideo(); 
} 
</script> 
</body> 
</html>"; //End of player creation string

//Then I create the html with the size of the screen
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:player,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width , [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height , @"5bCRDI1BESc"];

//And then I load the html into the webview
[self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
```

The HTML generated from this is the following

```
<html><head><style>body{margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;}</style></head> 
<body> 
<iframe id="player" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" width="320px" height="480px" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/5bCRDI1BESc?playsinline=1&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;enablejsapi=1"></iframe> <script src="http://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vflvlw_TO.js" async=""></script><script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script><script> var tag = document.createElement('script'); tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api"; var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag); 
var player; function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() { 
player = new YT.Player('player', { width:'320px', height:'480px', 
videoId:'5bCRDI1BESc',
playerVars: {playsinline : 1, rel:0, showinfo:0}, 
events: { 'onReady': onPlayerReady, } }); 
} 
function onPlayerReady(event) { event.target.playVideo(); } </script>  </body></html>
```

But the result is not the same as in iOS 6, where the player fills out into the the whitespce (webview). Here is a picture

[image: Player not filling out into space]

If I then **double (the screen size!)** to 640px and 960px the width and height going into the HTML!?

[image: double the screen size not either filling out into space]

**Does anybody know what happened either to the YouTube API or Safari browser in iOS 7?**

Comment: Have you tried setting the width of the player to 100%?

Comment: Yes I have tried that and its just the same result as setting the heigt and width to the device size. That is what is so baffling :-/

Comment: In your app,the whole screen view is a webView, or just the video view with play/pause button is the webView?

Comment: The webView covers all the white space from the top down to the icon bar (and of course including the youtube player you see).

Answer (score 1):

This is my current implementation:

```
let webView = UIWebView(...)

// get the ID of the video you want to play
let videoID = "zN-GGeNPQEg" // https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zN-GGeNPQEg

// Replace the height and width of the player here to match your UIWebView's  frame rect
let embededHTML = "<html><body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'><script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script><script type='text/javascript'>function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){ytplayer=new YT.Player('playerId',{events:{onReady:onPlayerReady}})}function onPlayerReady(a){a.target.playVideo();}</script><iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='\(self.view.frame.size.width)' height='\(self.view.frame.size.height)' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/\(videoID)?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=1&autoplay=1' frameborder='0'></body></html>"

// Load your webView with the HTML we just set up
webView.loadHTMLString(embededHTML, baseURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL)
```

This is inside of a `UIViewController` and I'm passing in the frame of the view controller's `view` as the width and height of the player.  You should resize your player accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I use `html` youtube players somewhat frequently from a `UIWebView` and use this code.

```
NSString* embedHTML = @"\
<html><head>\
<style type=\"text/css\">\
body {\
background-color: transparent;\
color: white;\
}\
</style>\
</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
<embed id=\"yt\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
width=\"240\" height=\"150\"></embed>\
</body></html>";

NSString* url = [NSURL URLWithString:_detailModel.video];
NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, url];
nurl = [NSURL URLWithString:html];

[_videoWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

Where it says `width=\"240\" height=\"150\` is the thumbnail size.  The actual size of the video defaults to the whole screen.  This works flawlessly for youtube videos, but any other video (vimeo, etc) you have to take the `type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\"` out.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>      
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      width: '480',
      height: '280',
      videoId: 'rynvewVe21Y',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady}
    });
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }
</script>​
```

Try to use this script where you can change height & width as per your requirement.

Comment: Sorry friend this one did not work any better than my code. Now to check the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Some food for thought - There are some changes to YouTubes iFrame Api see https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference in particular since July 2012,

the player_api is deprecated and replaced by the iFrame_api.

in particular

```
tag.src = \"http://www.youtube.com/player_api\";
```

is replaced by

```
 tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
```

and

```
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady()
```

is replaced by

```
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()
```

It does specify that both will be supported for some time, Which leads me to suspect that some of the parameters you used may possibly be unavailable in the old API and maybe causing your issues, -

playerVars: {playsinline : 1, rel:0, showinfo:0} are relatively new circa 2014 a full 2 years after the old API was deprecated.

Disclaimer: The first version of my app features an embedded youtube player, however  since IOS 6.0 I discovered m.youtube.com and I find the controls a little better than what I have been coding and I've stuck to it since.  Consequently I am not able to test this but I believe it is worth trying in your case.

Below is an excerpt of the documentation for your use:

July 19, 2012

This update contains the following changes:

The Requirements section has been updated to indicate that any web page using the IFrame API must also implement the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady function. Previously, the section indicated that the required function was named onYouTubePlayerAPIReady. Code samples throughout the document have also been updated to use the new name.

Note: To ensure that this change does not break existing implementations, both names will work. If, for some reason, your page has an onYouTubeIframeAPIReady function and an onYouTubePlayerAPIReady function, both functions will be called, and the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady function will be called first.

Good Luck

Comment: This looked the most promising thank you very much so I have been playing around with it for few hours without luck. I think I will now create a new empty project just to try this out. There has to be something that changed so some setting is now off. Since this is a side project I might not be back until the weekend. :-)

Comment: If I use the code from the link you provided that code "works" it that it plays the video but in full ios sceen but not in a HTML5 inline mode. I I try to ad the playerVars I only get a white screen with no video at all. Just like the playerVars are screwing it all up. Im lost..

Comment: If you are talking about m.youtube.com, its the youtube site that accepts parameters it serves my purposes, I also do not have to deal on Flash vs. HTML5 -  but it is not as flexible as the iFrame API which embeds the YTPlayer inside a webpage. .... PS your parameters are HTML5 only  - I am not sure how well it will work with Flash Videos, there is another set  I think they call it AS3 player that allows FlashVideo playback - Not really sure if this is your problem but as you know, Mobile Safari does not support flash video on its own.

Answer (score 0):

The default viewport width for UIWebView is 980.  Set scalesPageToFit:YES on your UIWebView.